# Rails send email via pop up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a form, which has a field which onclick() leads to opening up of a pop up (Invite Importer).

In this pop up, the customer has to input certain information and when it is inputted, I want all the information to be saved and email to be triggered with the inputted email. All this should happen when I click on submit (shown in below image as "Speichern").

How would I do it?

I have thought about creating 2 forms. One popup and the other base, but the submit button would lead to both of them being submitted.

how do you i save and submit email with pop up without the other form being submitted.

[image: pop up to send email]

Comment: You could use JS to submit the popup form and then the other form will stay like it is. Google for submitting form through ajax will give you a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the html for the second form is not inside the main form. That will cause issues. You also probably want the modal form to be `remote: true` so that it will be submitted via AJAX. Instead of:

```
<%= form_for @model do |form| %>
  ...
  <%= form.text_field :foo, onclick: 'openEmailModal()' %>

  <div class="modal etc" id="email-modal">
    <%= form_for @email do |form2| %>
        ...
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You will have:

```
<%= form_for @model do |form| %>
  ...
  <%= form.text_field :foo, onclick: 'openEmailModal()' %>
<% end %>

<div class="modal hide etc" id="email-modal">
    <%= form_for @email, remote: true do |form| %>
        ...
    <% end %>
</div>
```

In your views you can create a file named create.js.erb for example that would do something like:

```
closeEmailModal(); // this is just straight javascript
$('#notices').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'my_partial') %>"); // reuse html your partials in JS
$('#notices').html("<%= j(render 'my_partial') %>"); // or use j (it's an alias for escape_javascript)
alert('I did stuff!');
```